# If an axial flow dc motor is rated at 750 Nm @ 380 V dc ... what would the Nm be @ 190 V dc?

Tags: voltage

Not knowing if voltage changes Newton Meters of Torque ... the question is:

Does the peak torque remain unchanged at half the volts (190v DC vs. 380v DC) and

the roll off curve starts sooner (lower rpm)?  Certainly Kilowatts (power) are

proportional to volts ... but it seems Newton Meters (torque) are related to amps?

Additional Facts:  750 Nm is Peak Torque (60 sec) @ 360 Amps (rms) ... Efficiency

is 95% ... Peak Power is 100Kw @ 380v.

Comment: Capital N is Newtons, the SI unit of force. Lowercase n is nano-, SI prefix for 10^-9.

Answer (score 1):

Nanometers are \$nm\$. \$Nm\$ is a unit of torque, the [newton meter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_metre). They are not at all the same thing.

Power is the *product* of voltage and current:

$$ P = VE $$

so yes, it is proportional to voltage, but it is also proportional to current.

For all electromagnetic motors (that is, nearly all electric motors, but not electrostatic motors), torque is proportional to current, and speed is proportional to voltage. Electrical power is proportional to mechanical power, which is the product of torque and angular velocity.

If a motor claims "\$750 Nm @ 380 V\$", what is probably meant is that the *maximum* torque at that voltage is \$750 Nm\$. The torque could in fact be much less: if there is no load on the motor, then the torque will be just enough to overcome friction, which is small. The motor will develop maximum torque, and current will be at the maximum, when the motor is stalled (that is, speed is 0). In this condition, the current is limited by the DC resistance of the motor. From the information you've provided, we can't know what this resistance is, but we can reasonably assume it's a constant value.

According to Ohm's law, the current through a resistance is proportional to the voltage:

$$ V = IR $$

So, whatever \$R\$ is, if the voltage is reduced from \$380V\$ to \$190V\$, the current, and also the torque, will be reduced by a similar fraction. So:

$$ 750 Nm \frac{190V}{380V} = 370Nm $$

At least, this is a good first order approximation.

Comment: A word error ... Nm ... Newton meters ... of course! Here is an example: the Remy HVH-410 motor produces 800 Nm of peak torque (60 seconds) at 200v, 400v, 600v or 700v.  Torque is constant in this example, however the roll off curve starts at lower rpm at 200v than 700v. I have the power test graph to prove this.  Could it be different on one dc brushless motor to another?  The torque is calculated from amps ... is that true? Can anyone comment on this?

Comment: @Jake torque is proportional to current, less losses in the motor like \$I^2R\$ resistive losses in the windings. Depending on the motor, higher voltage may not get you any more *rated* torque because the power limit of the motor means you can't apply the full stall current to the motor without overheating it. If you did, you would get more torque at higher voltage, and then your motor would probably overheat. Having less drive voltage available means less to overcome back-emf, so you are able to drive less current, thus lower torque, at a given speed.

Comment: @Jake see for example section 3.1 at http://lancet.mit.edu/motors/motors3.html for torque vs. speed graph of a motor that *isn't* power limited. It's similar to the graph in the datasheet you reference, without the top of the triangle chopped off.

Comment: PHIL ... Thank You for all your input.  You have figured it out ... the peak torque requires 'x' volts and 'x' current.  Lets assume peak torque comes at

Comment: PHIL ... Thank You for all your input.  You have figured it out ... the peak torque requires 'x' volts and 'x' current.  Lets assume peak torque comes at 200v ... any additional voltage will not yield more torque.  These motors are tested at higher volts to show higher Kw ... not torque.  Seems that maximum peak torque will be available on most DC Brushless motors @ 200v with the required Amps (rms).